# .txt to HTML string with variables python

Tags: python, html, gmail-api, python-3.8

I have a script to send emails using Gmail's API:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    service = get_service()
    user_id = 'me'
    sender = 'myemail@gmail.com'
    recipients_list = ['to@gmail.com']
    var1 = input('Type whatever here: ')
    subject = f'Reasonable subject in {var1}'
    body = f'<h1>Hello World<\h1><p>{var1}'
    attached_file = r'C:\Somefile.pdf'
for item in recipients_list:
    msg = create_message_with_attachment(sender, subject=subject, body=body, file=attached_file, to=item)
    send_message(service, user_id, msg)
```

I've managed to get the string of the variable `body` from a .txt file using Pathlib but I can't figure out how to make so the email sent in interpreted as HTML as well as `var1` be interpreted as a variable instead of part of the sting. How could I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I realize I've misexplained. I meant the HTML part is fine, but the .txt file with the body of the email includes variables (i.e. `var1`) that I need to be interpreted as such instead of part of the string.

I.e.:

**Hello World**

How can make this a {var1}

Also here's the function that creates the email:

```
def create_message_with_attachment(sender, to, subject, body, file):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject

    msg = MIMEText(body, 'html')
    message.attach(msg)

    (content_type, encoding) = mimetypes.guess_type(file)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = 'application/octet-stream'

    (main_type, sub_type) = content_type.split('/', 1)

    if main_type == 'text':
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            msg = MIMEText(f.read().decode('utf-8'), _subtype=sub_type)
    elif main_type == 'image':
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            msg = MIMEImage(f.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    elif main_type == 'audio':
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            msg = MIMEAudio(f.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
    else:
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
            msg.set_payload(f.read())

    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    email.encoders.encode_base64(msg)
    message.attach(msg)

    raw_msg = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode('utf-8'))
    return {'raw': raw_msg.decode('utf-8')}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the message, you should add an additional `html` parameter to the `MIMEText` class.

Therefore, your code will look something like this

```
subject = 'Reasonable subject in' + var2
body = '<h1>Hello World<\h1>'+ var1
```

And when creating the email message, it should have a structure similar to this - notice the addition of the `html` parameter.

```
 message = MIMEText(message, 'html')
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    encodedmsg = urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(message))
    result = {
      'raw': encodedmsg.decode()
    }
```

#### Reference

- [Python email: Examples](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html).

Comment: Hey, I've edited the question as I'm a dumba** and misexplained,  thanks for answering tho!